# Can Vital Strike be used in conjunction with a far-reaching sight on a firearm?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, actions

The far-reaching sight is a magical upgrade for two-handed firearms that allows to snipe from afar :

> A firearm wielder can choose to spend a *full-round action* to make a *single shot with a firearm* that has this sight. When she does, she can resolve the attack against the touch AC of her target regardless of the range increment.

Does this mean feats such as Vital Strike that apply to standard attack actions cannot be used in conjunction with this upgrade ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**They cannot be used together.**

As you stated, from [Vital Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/vital-strike-combat---final):

> When you use the attack action

The attack action is a specific type of [action](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Actions-In-Combat):

> Attack Action: An attack action is a type of standard action. Some combat options can modify only this specific sort of action. When taking an attack action, you can apply all appropriate options that modify an attack action.

Because the *single shot with a firearm* is a full-round action, they cannot be used together.  For them to function together, the shot would need to modify the attack action.

Comment: A great example of this is Vital Strike and Cleave.  Cleave is a special type of attack, not an attack action, so they cannot be used together (even though they are both standard actions that attack).